# How can I stream music/audio from Android and PC to Android device via WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, audio

I've searched for this for some time, and I've found several options that almost works.

I have an Android device connected to my stereo and I want to be able to connect to it with either my PC or my Android phone and play whatever music I'm playing on the phone/PC on the device instead.

I've tried [SoundWire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree&hl=en), which sort of works with PC->Android, though the sound is sometimes choppy, and I have to connect from the Android device instead of from the PC.

I've tried [Remote Droid Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sequels.remotedroidplayer&hl=en) and [Twonky](http://twonky.com/), that works with Music that's already on my device, and [twonky beam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pv.twonkybeam&hl=en) seems to work if I find something on YouTube, but since most music I play is on Google Play Music, that doesn't do me much good either.

So does anyone have a solution for this. What I basically need is to replace my long jack->rca cable with an Android device, if you can put it like that.

Answer (score 5):

## WiFi Speaker

#### Stream all Audio from PC to Android!

## About

> Use WiFi Speaker to stream all audio from a computer to an Android device in realtime. Just run the server on your Windows PC, and the app on your Android. The server is completely free, as is the app.
>
> Setup is easy:
>
> - [Download and install](http://pixelatedmind.com/downloads/WiFiSpeakerServer.zip) the server on your media PC.
> - Get the [WiFi Speaker Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pixelface.android.audio) on Google Play
> - Enjoy tunes!

## Links

- Google Play Store: [WiFi Speaker <sup>(Free)</sup>](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pixelface.android.audio)
- Google Play Store: [WiFi Speaker Pro <sup>(Paid, no ads)</sup>](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pixelface.android.audio.paid)
- pixelatedmind.com: [Media PC Server for WinXP/Vista/7](http://pixelatedmind.com/downloads/WiFiSpeakerServer.zip)

## Screenshots:

[image: WiFi Speaker Screenshots]

**Note:** I'm the developer.

Comment: Looks cool - I'll check it out asap - any chance you could make a client app for android as well? ;o)

Comment: #Edit: Server app for android of course...

Comment: ive considered this, but theres no way to get audio from androids sound card. i could write one which just recorded from the mic, but i dont know how useful that would be.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing a server for Android now.  The server can be used to capture an Android server device audio, or an external audio source.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

1. [Plex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plexapp.android&hl=en): (paid - $4.99) streams videos, photos, and music from your PC to lots of devices including Android phones and tablets.
2. Some sort of [VLC PC-to-phone streaming app](https://encrypted.google.com/search?oq=vlc+stream+site%3Aplay.google.com&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vlc+stream+site%3Aplay.google.com&qscrl=1)?
3. [Audiogalaxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audiogalaxy&hl=en)
4. [Airplayit](http://www.airplayit.com/)
5. If you are not picky about the desktop to Android part, maybe [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music) will be suitable for you?
6. These might also help: [CNET: How to stream music from your PC to Android remotely](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20077603-285/how-to-stream-music-from-your-pc-to-android-remotely/), [Android Authority: Best Free Apps to Stream Videos from PC to Android Phone](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-free-apps-to-stream-videos-from-pc-to-android-phone-46394/)

Personally I've only used Plex, Google Play Music, and [VLC Stream & Convert Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.traveldevel.android.vlc.license&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks!
1-3. Plex-AG seems to be only streaming stuff that's on the device, or whatever webpage I load within the app
4. Seems to be playing my music on my phone, google music does that for me
2. I haven't tried that, but my guess is that I have to load whatever I'm playing within vlc
5. I have google music and love it, but I want to be able to decide what to play on my stereo from my phone - and as far as I can figure out, it can't do that. Nexus Q isnt avaiable i europe (i believe).
6. I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

I've settled with [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=en) which can act both as a server and a client (on different devices), and it can play my Google Music account.

It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it'll do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gmote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gmote.client.android). Among other features, it notes on the Play Store description:

> Stream music from your computer to phone!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following two apps:

## For PC:

### [Airfoil for Windows](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/)

> Send any audio from your PC to AirPort Express units, Apple TVs, iPhones and iPods Touch, and even other PCs and Macs, all in sync! Use Airfoil with web-based audio like Pandora, music services like Spotify, Rdio, MOG, and WiMP, or any other audio playing on your computer. Airfoil for Windows gives you your audio on AirPlay devices all around the house.

## For Android devices:

### [AirBubble](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.airbubble)

> AirBubble is a lightweight AirPlay audio receiver. It will appear in AirPlay applications (such as itunes) as a device you can play music to. It works in the background, streaming music to your Android device.
>
> This version is fully featured but will exit 30 minutes after each app start (you can start the app as many times as you want). This can be unlocked with the AirBubble License app.