# How can I stream audio from another device via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio

> **Related question:** [How can I stream music/audio from Android and PC to Android device via WiFi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34545/how-can-i-stream-music-audio-from-android-and-pc-to-android-device-via-wifi)

I would like to stream audio from a Bluetooth-enabled "dumb phone" to my Andoid phone. The Android phone is running Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.4). I have searched the Play store for such an app, but all I could find were applications that did the opposite (stream audio *from* the Android phone instead of *to* it).

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: George, please note that questions like *is there an app for X* are off topic here (see our [FAQ] for details). I took the freedom to slightly re-phrase it to prevent it from being closed. Your problem is not "to find an app", but "to stream audio", right? :)

Comment: Hello, Can you please help me regarding this same ? Any example code ? I cant find any tutorial to stream audio. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789394/how-to-stream-audio-from-one-android-device-to-another-android-device-via-blueto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP)](https://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/ProfilesAndProtocols/A2DP.htm) is a source/sink configuration. In an normal scenario, you have a source (for example, and Android phone) and a sink (Bluetooth headset/speakers). But in your case, the Android phone would have to act as a sink to the dumbphone source. This is not currently supported, even though the phone supports the A2DP profile.

One solution would be to install a custom Bluetooth stack, which defines which profiles are supported on the device. This would additionally require a software component that can bypass the Android Framework and use the stack directly, since the framework lacks A2DP sink support. So far, no such modifications can be found.

Comment: I'm guessing such a modification would also require rooting the device?

Comment: At the very least, probably even flashing a custom kernel/ROM.